# dfu-programmer 0.6.2 error message during ./bootstrap.sh

Tags: macos, terminal, arduino-uno, dfu

I'm after little help. I'm working on a hobby project to create a mouse from an Arduino with an accelerometer.

For part of this I need to change the firmware on the atmega16u2. I have a mac so to do this I am trying to use the dfu-programmer.

When I use the ./bootstrap.sh command line in terminal I get the following error messages displayed. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on what they mean and if this would prevent the program from working ?

```
DJ:dfu-programmer-0.6.2 hd334$ ./bootstrap.sh
sh: autom4te: command not found
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 127
./bootstrap.sh: line 3: autoheader: command not found
sh: autoconf: command not found
automake: error: autoconf failed with exit status: 127
./bootstrap.sh: line 5: autoconf: command not found
DJ:dfu-programmer-0.6.2 hd334$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `autom4te`, `autoheader`, `autoconf`, `libusb-compat` and `libusb` before executing `dfu-programmer`.

All those `auto*` prerequisites are included in `autoconf` package. I recommend you to install `home-brew` package manager. It can do these things automatically. Although there is `dfu-programmer` package in the repository, so you can install it automatically too.

- To install `home-brew`, run this command in your Terminal:

  ```
  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  ```
- **Recommended**: After that, install `dfu-programmer` with this command:

  ```
  brew install dfu-programmer
  ```
- If you want to install prerequisites only, run this command:

  ```
  brew install autoconf libusb libusb-compat
  ```

  then rerun `./bootstrap.sh`.